# How to fill in the array in constructor

Tags: java

I have a class Wagon and a class Train which are in HAS a relations.
I've created an array of Wagons and need to use in Train constructor (as i understand)
But I do not understand h**ow to use an array in constructor and fill it to make code run**

Here is my code.
Thanks for explanation !

```
public class Wagon {
    private int m;

    public int getM() {
        return m;
    }


    public Wagon(int m) {
        this.m = m;
    }


    private Wagon[] wag = new Wagon[3];
```

```
public class Train {

    private Wagon[] wag;

    public Train(Wagon[] wag){
        this.wag=wag;
    }


    public int findCargo() {

        int x = 0;

        for (Wagon w : wag) {

            x += w.getM();
        }

        return x;
    }


    public int findAverage() {

        return this.findCargo() / wag.length;
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Train train = new Train( new Wagon[]{8,9,7});
        System.out.println(train.findCargo());
```

Comment: Why does your wagon have an array of 3 wagons?

Comment: because i want train to have 3 wagons)

Comment: You can initialize the Wagon array with integers. Instead please create like, new Wagon[]{new Wagon(8), new Wagon(9), new Wagon(7)};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Miss Understand The Syntax Of Array.

Ref :: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

```
// declares an array of integers
int[] anArray = { 100, 200, 300 };
// declares an array of String's
String[] strArray= { "100", "200", "300" };
```

If you want to create array of **`Wagon`** then

```
Wagon[] wagons = new Wagon[]{new Wagon(8), new Wagon(9), new Wagon(7)};
```

Replace Code With

```
Wagon[] wagons = new Wagon[]{new Wagon(8), new Wagon(9), new Wagon(7)};
Train train = new Train(wegons);
System.out.println(train.findCargo());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the variable arguments syntax

```
public Train(Wagon... wag){
        this.wag=wag;
    }
```

Then you can call it like this

```
Train train = new Train(new Wagon(1), new Wagon(2), new Wagon(3));
```

Answer (score 2):

This `new Wagon[]{8,9,7}` doesn't work, you try to create an Wagon array and fill it with `ints`. You need to fill it with Wagons object

The valid one is `new Wagon[]{new Wagon(8), new Wagon(9), new Wagon(7)}`

```
Wagon[] wagons = new Wagon[]{new Wagon(8), new Wagon(9), new Wagon(7)};
Train train = new Train(wagons);
```